# Debug SSRS C# DLL Called from Java Application

Tags: c#, debugging, dll

I am in the process of implementing Microsoft SQL Service Reporting Services for my company.  SSRS will be called from our company's Java web app.  We have decided to use a single sign-on approach when requesting a report from SSRS from the Java web app.  With that being the case, we are utilizing forms authentication via a custom security extension to enable single sign-on.  As you may already know, after the user submits the UILogon.aspx page, a ticket is created and placed in the cookie called sqlAuthCookie.  This cookie (ticket) is then used for authorization whenever the user makes any subsequent requests to SSRS.

The problem I am having is that it appears that the form authentication code, that is written in C# and resides on the SSRS server as a .dll, is not creating a ticket and placing it in the sqlAuthCookie cookie.  I've inspected the sqlAuthCookie cookie within the Java web app. by accessing the RSAuthenticationHeader in the response header and the sqlAuthCookie cookie does not contain a value.

So what I want to know is if there is a way that I can put the form authentication code, which is a .dll, in debug within Visual Studio, so that when I log into SSRS from the Java web application, I can step through this code to verify whether or not it is creating the ticket for the cookie.

Please let me know if you require a code snippet.

**Code**

```
private void BtnLogon_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
         bool passwordVerified = false;
         try
         {
            ReportServerProxy server = new ReportServerProxy();

            string reportServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"];
            string instanceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerInstance"];

            // Get the server URL from the report server using WMI
            server.Url = AuthenticationUtilities.GetReportServerUrl(reportServer, instanceName);

            server.LogonUser(TxtUser.Text, TxtPwd.Text, null);

            passwordVerified = true;

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            lblMessage.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ex.Message); ;
            return;
         }
         if (passwordVerified == true)
         {
            lblMessage.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
              UILogon_aspx.LoginSuccess);
            string redirectUrl =
               Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
            if (redirectUrl != null)
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
            else
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(
                  "./Folder.aspx", false);
         }
         else
         {
            lblMessage.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
             UILogon_aspx.InvalidUsernamePassword);
         }
      }
   }

   // Because the UILogon uses the Web service to connect to the report server
   // you need to extend the server proxy to support authentication ticket
   // (cookie) management
   public class ReportServerProxy : ReportingService2005
   {
      protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
      {
         HttpWebRequest request;
         request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
         // Create a cookie jar to hold the request cookie
         CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
         request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
         Cookie authCookie = AuthCookie;
         // if the client already has an auth cookie
         // place it in the request's cookie container
         if (authCookie != null)
            request.CookieContainer.Add(authCookie);
         request.Timeout = -1;
         request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language",
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"]);
         return request;
      }

      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2201:DoNotRaiseReservedExceptionTypes")]
      protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
      {
         WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
         string cookieName = response.Headers["RSAuthenticationHeader"];
         // If the response contains an auth header, store the cookie
         if (cookieName != null)
         {
            Utilities.CustomAuthCookieName = cookieName;
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
            Cookie authCookie = webResponse.Cookies[cookieName];
            // If the auth cookie is null, throw an exception
            if (authCookie == null)
            {
               throw new Exception(
                  "Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser");
            }
            // otherwise save it for this request
            AuthCookie = authCookie;
            // and send it to the client
            Utilities.RelayCookieToClient(authCookie);
         }
         return response;
      }

      private Cookie AuthCookie
      {
         get
         {
            if (m_Authcookie == null)
               m_Authcookie =
               Utilities.TranslateCookie(
                  HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Utilities.CustomAuthCookieName]);
            return m_Authcookie;
         }
         set
         {
            m_Authcookie = value;
         }
      }
      private Cookie m_Authcookie = null;
   }

   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1812:AvoidUninstantiatedInternalClasses")]
   internal sealed class Utilities
   {
      internal static string CustomAuthCookieName
      {
         get
         {
            lock (m_cookieNamelockRoot)
            {
               return m_cookieName;
            }
         }
         set
         {
            lock (m_cookieNamelockRoot)
            {
               m_cookieName = value;
            }
         }
      }

private static string m_cookieName;
      private static object m_cookieNamelockRoot = new object();

      private static HttpCookie TranslateCookie(Cookie netCookie)
      {
         if (netCookie == null)
            return null;
         HttpCookie webCookie = new HttpCookie(netCookie.Name, netCookie.Value);
         // Add domain only if it is dotted - IE doesn't send back the cookie 
         // if we set the domain otherwise
         if (netCookie.Domain.IndexOf('.') != -1)
            webCookie.Domain = netCookie.Domain;
         webCookie.Expires = netCookie.Expires;
         webCookie.Path = netCookie.Path;
         webCookie.Secure = netCookie.Secure;
         return webCookie;
      }

      internal static Cookie TranslateCookie(HttpCookie webCookie)
      {
         if (webCookie == null)
            return null;
         Cookie netCookie = new Cookie(webCookie.Name, webCookie.Value);
         if (webCookie.Domain == null)
            netCookie.Domain =
               HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
         netCookie.Expires = webCookie.Expires;
         netCookie.Path = webCookie.Path;
         netCookie.Secure = webCookie.Secure;
         return netCookie;
      }

      internal static void RelayCookieToClient(Cookie cookie)
      {
         // add the cookie if not already in there
         if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookie.Name] == null)
         {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(cookie.Name);
         }

         HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(TranslateCookie(cookie));
      }
   }
```

Comment: Couple thoughts (1) Yes, I would include a code snippet, and any other config (2) The "as you may already know" -> I'd assume, we probably don't already know especially given the next point (3) "the custom security extension" - can you ensure that is working properly? If that is the same as your .dll, why not get the source? and (4) Assuming that's not easy, any idea where the failure is occurring? Logs, etc?

Comment: I added a code snippet for review.

Comment: I do have access to the source code for the custom security extension.  I have looked at the logs produced by SSRS and there is nothing in them shows errors or a failure.  That's why I would like to know if there is a way to put custom security extension, which is a dll, in debug mode so I can step through the code.

Comment: Yes, though you need to build a debug version of the .dll. These [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-dll-projects?view=vs-2019) are for VS but should be same for Visual Code: _Make sure to build a Debug version of the DLL before you start debugging. To debug a DLL, a calling app must be able to find its .pdb file and any other files the DLL requires._